# why order of parameter remain same even arguments are passed as named arguments? in javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, parameter-passing

for example in python:

```
def dfde(name,age):
       print(age)
       print(name)
       print(age)

 dfde(age=27,name="dfd")
```

will give a output as:

```
27
dfd
27
```

but samething in javascript will give the output as:

```
let dfde = function(name, age){
    console.log(age);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(age);
}

dfde(age=27, name="dfd")
```

will give output as:

```
dfd
27
dfd
```

> even arguments are passed as named arguments,

why is that?

Comment: Your python code is using named arguments and javascript code contains positional arguments. When you use named arguments function will check arguments depending on the name and when you pass positional argument it check using position of the argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even arguments are passed as named arguments,

There are no named arguments.

```
dfde(age = 27, name = "dfd")
```

is the same as:

```
dfde(27, "dfd")
```

(Additionally `age = 27` creates a new global variable age and assigns the value to it)

---

To use something like named arguments in js you have to pass an obiect literal and deconstruct that:

```
function dfde({name, age}) {
  console.log(name, age);
}

dfde({ name: "dfd", age: 27 });
// Same as
dfde({ age: 27, name: "dfd" });
```

Comment: What if we need to pass default values also to function declaration?
can we do like:

let scoreName = function ({name:"edfe", age:27}){ 
    console.log(name,age):
};

by calling function as scoreName() will it give out put as:

edfe 27

Comment: @mohammad yes just do `function({name = "sgdh", age = 27 } = {}) {`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there's no named parameters in JavaScript. It recognizes parameters by the order of precedence. So, you should do this:

```js
let dfde = function(name, age){
    console.log(age);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(age);
}

dfde(name="dfd", age=27)  // it just declares variable to global scope as `var`
dfde("dfd", 27) // same as above
```

You can also, log the way the function is receiving the parameters using `arguments` like this:

```js
let dfde = function(name, age){
    console.log(arguments);    // no named parameters
}

dfde(name="dfd", age=27)
```

If you want to use something like named parameter refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259663/5349542).