# javascript define arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am trying to create a function in JS that is taking a lot of arguments but does not always use all of them.  What I would like to do is define which argument I am putting a refrence in for.  This is what I am thinking but not working like I would like it to.

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3){
let arg1 = arg1;
let arg2 = arg2;
let arg3 = arg3;

}

foo(arg2:'sets value of arg2');
```

I would like to be able to skip putting in an argument for the first position and only pass info for the second argument.  How can I do this?

Comment: Also have a look at [named arguments in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259580/why-order-of-parameter-remain-same-even-arguments-are-passed-as-named-arguments#51259663)

Comment: Thank you to everyone's input, it helped me in making this.
https://github.com/dambergn/js-password-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It would require the caller to pass an object.

```js
function foo({arg, arg2}={}) {
  let arg_1 = arg;
  let arg_2 = arg2;
  
  console.log(arg_1);
  console.log(arg_2);
  // Code
}

foo({arg2: 2});
```

if you need to set the default parameters you can do it this way `function foo({arg = '', arg2 = ''}={})`

Comment: If it helped you, make the right answer to help those in need, but it was a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

You could [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a sparse array with the value for the wanted argument without changing the function's signature.

```js
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

foo(...[, 42]);
```

Or use an object with the key for a specified element

```js
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}

foo(...Object.assign([], { 1: 42 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in `null` as some of the parameters if they are not needed.

```js
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3){
console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
foo(null, 30, null);
```