# Default parameters order wrong result

Tags: javascript, default-arguments

I've seen an example giving wrong output when I try to run it. I don't understand why I get the wrong result while it is supplied in order. At the last call, I expect `a=7, b=10`. What's wrong?

```
"use strict";

function f(a=1, b=2){ return(`a=${a}, b=${b}`) }
f() // a=1, b=2
f(a=5) // a=5, b=2
f(a=7, b=10) // a=7, b=10
f(b=10, a=7) // Order is required: a=10, b=7
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have keyword arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing javascript method params as object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453464/passing-javascript-method-params-as-object-literal)

Comment: @FilipSeman no.

Comment: To clarify the specific behaviour here, `a=7` and `b=10` are *assignments*, which are expressions evaluating to the value assigned. Nothing to do with the names of the parameters defined in the function, you could do `f(foo=1, bar=2)` and it would still be the same as `f(1, 2)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why order of parameter remain same even arguments are passed as named arguments? in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259580/why-order-of-parameter-remain-same-even-arguments-are-passed-as-named-arguments)

Comment: @jonrsharpe so, what's going on in detail if we do `b=10` as in the example?

Comment: The thing I said in my comment above, an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters provided are handled in the order defined in the function.  To achieve something similar, you can use an object parameter:

```
function f(prmObj){ return(`a=${prmObj.a}, b=${prmObj.b}`) }

f({b: 10, a: 7})  // a=7, b=10
```

Comment: Is there any technical definition of 
_"Parameters provided are handled in the order"_  such as on mozilla developer platorm?

Comment: [MDN functions reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Comment: @jslearner the MDN docs cover functions in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions. Parameter order *must* be maintained, otherwise functions would be unusable.